# Cannot connect to X server error

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, xserver

I’ve compiled Qt for embedded (RaspberryPi). Then compiled an application and sent both libraries and app to raspberry.

When I wanted to run an application (./application -qws) I received an error: – cannot connect to X server

I want to use Qt which will be writing to virtual frame buffer instead of X server.

Do you know what could be wrong? My another compilation with static linkage works fine.